# Questions reading Ionic 2 documentation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to learn Ionic 2 and that's become a very difficult task

I'm trying to get all the contacts of the device and list them in the app.

I go to the plugin page

https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/contacts/

And it says `find(fields, options)`

Where `fields` is `ContactFieldType[]`

But WHAT IS `ContactFieldType` ? Where do I find it?

I have been through the same problem several times in my quest of learning Ionic2.

Answer (score 0):

Ionic Native is just a wrapper for the actual cordova plugins.
[Check here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/)
You can find the complete documentation in the respective cordova repo as well since the usage is the same.

In your case [ContactFieldType is described here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#contactfieldtype)

> The ContactFieldType object is an enumeration of possible field types, such as 'phoneNumbers' or 'emails', that could be used to control which contact properties must be returned back from contacts.find() method

Comment: are you refering to this https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/launch-navigator/ ?

Answer (score 0):

**Using Ionic 3 get all the contacts of the device and list them in the app**

Step 1: using command prompt install it

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
```

Step 2: using command prompt install it

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/contacts
```

Step3: open **app.module.ts**

```
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

providers: [
    Contacts
  ]
```

Step 4: example open **home.html**

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of allContacts">
    {{ item._objectInstance.displayName }} 
  </button>  
</ion-list>
```

Step 5: example open **home.ts**

```
import { Contacts } from '@ionic-native/contacts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-list',
  templateUrl: 'list.html'
})
export class ListPage {

allContacts:any;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private contacts: Contacts) { 

     this.contacts.find(['displayName', 'name', 'phoneNumbers', 'emails'], {filter: "", multiple: true})
    .then(data => {
      this.allContacts = data;
      console.log("data"+JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  }
}
```

Hope it's working fine refer it :)